# Where are `_stdlib_getTypeName()` & `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName()` declared? -- Swift

Tags: swift

I'm toying with some introspection in Swift and it seems like if you want to get the class of an object in a printable version, these are the best options.  (introduced in beta 6.0).

```
_stdlib_getTypeName(someClass)
_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(someClass) // A slightly cleaner version
```

I was hoping to find other introspection methods, but unfortunately, command clicking the methods take me to the Swift header and they're not declared there.

My other option would be to type `_stdlib` and wait for autocomplete or control space to see my options.  Unfortunately, none of these methods autocomplete.

Is there a file where these and other stdlib functions are declared, or is there documentation for these methods anywhere?

Comment: Demangle has been rewritten in Swift by Matt Gallagher. See:  https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlDemangle/blob/master/CwlDemangle/CwlDemangle.swift

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer to my question via a tips and tricks blog post from realm [here](http://realm.io/news/favorite-swift-tips-and-tricks-of-2014/)  -- notably, the post by JP Simard.

The best way to see other methods along these lines is to go to your terminal and type:

```
cd `xcode-select -p`/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx
```

And then enter the following:

```
nm -a libswiftCore.dylib | grep "T _swift_stdlib"
```

This will give you a readout of all available functions that looks something like this:

```
00000000001a43c0 T _swift_stdlib_NSObject_isEqual
00000000001a4490 T _swift_stdlib_NSStringHasPrefixNFD
00000000001a44f0 T _swift_stdlib_NSStringHasSuffixNFD
00000000001a4450 T _swift_stdlib_NSStringNFDHashValue
00000000001a2650 T _swift_stdlib_atomicCompareExchangeStrongPtr
00000000001a2670 T _swift_stdlib_atomicCompareExchangeStrongUInt32
00000000001a2690 T _swift_stdlib_atomicCompareExchangeStrongUInt64
00000000001a2700 T _swift_stdlib_atomicFetchAddUInt32
00000000001a2710 T _swift_stdlib_atomicFetchAddUInt64
00000000001a26f0 T _swift_stdlib_atomicLoadPtr
00000000001a26d0 T _swift_stdlib_atomicLoadUInt32
00000000001a26e0 T _swift_stdlib_atomicLoadUInt64
00000000001a26b0 T _swift_stdlib_atomicStoreUInt32
00000000001a26c0 T _swift_stdlib_atomicStoreUInt64
00000000001a4410 T _swift_stdlib_compareNSStringDeterministicUnicodeCollation
000000000017c560 T _swift_stdlib_conformsToProtocol
00000000001a5a80 T _swift_stdlib_demangleName
000000000017c8e0 T _swift_stdlib_dynamicCastToExistential1
000000000017c6f0 T _swift_stdlib_dynamicCastToExistential1Unconditional
00000000001a5910 T _swift_stdlib_getTypeName
```

I haven't found any documentation, but a lot of these function names are fairly explanatory and one can always discover a lot through trying them out!

Answer (score 3):

All answers are good, but the result of second step that we can not use. We dont even know is this function usable or correct...

I've been trapped in these result about 1 day.

Finally I dump all **funcitons** & **symbols** for ***stdlib*** from libswiftcore.dylib, i found this..

command:

```
nm  libswiftcore.dylib | grep "_stdlib_"
```

We can find one line from result:

```
00000000000b2ca0 T __TFSs19_stdlib_getTypeNameU__FQ_SS
```

Remove first underscore "_" then we get this:

```
_TFSs19_stdlib_getTypeNameU__FQ_SS
```

Maybe we can view this [website](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html) to understand the meaning of ***"_TFSs19_stdlib_getTypeNameU__FQ_SS"***,

But I think we can get the correct function description faster!!
So, we demangle like this below in xcode lldb window:

```
(lldb) p _stdlib_demangleName("_TFSs19_stdlib_getTypeNameU__FQ_SS")
(String) $R0 = "Swift._stdlib_getTypeName <A>(A) -> Swift.String"
```

Finally we can expose more undocumented functions in swift that we never seen before, we can try another one that we never heard like this:

```
(lldb) p _stdlib_demangleName("_TFSs24_stdlib_atomicLoadARCRefFT6objectGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGSqPSs9AnyObject____GSqPS0___")
(String) $R1 = "Swift._stdlib_atomicLoadARCRef (object : Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>>) -> Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>"
```

All clear~ Thank god!!

Share this to you, wish it can help~
:D